# Deduplication based on two column using PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Im really really new with PowerBi.

What i wanted to know whether PowerBI have this kind of capabilities,

For example:

[PowerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkgJE.png)

As u can see in situation A, column 1 got same email (a@a) as column 3.
After dedup, it will becomes as situation B .
As i mention before, this can be done using excel but if the record very large. Excel will break.
Just wondering whether PowerBI can do this kind of deduplication.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Hi @IslamElshobokshy, done edit my post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a helper column in the Power Query Editor. Like this:

1. Let's make this the source table
   [image]
2. Add a conditional column
   [image]
3. In [Custom] select Keep
   [image]
4. Remove the helper column [custom]

   [image]